# mysql error 2005 - Unknown MySQL server host 'localhost'(11001)

Tags: mysql, database, authentication, connection, mysql-error

I was using mysql 5.6.11. It usually turned down and show me this:

> 2005 - Unknown MySQL server host 'localhost'(11001).

Currently my resolution is to turn off the network, then it returns to normal. I had searched a lot, but no answer is revalent to it. So, does anyone know the reason?

Comment: Did you try to ping localhost with your network on?

Comment: Hope this article would help you: http://faq.webyog.com/content/23/17/en/error-no-2005-unknown-mysql-server-host.html

Comment: @Himanshu Bhardwaj :I'll try tomorrow when the error appears,thanks for the answer!

Comment: @Sam :Thanks for your answer,but I did't found the answer via that article,thanks again.

Comment: @HimanshuBhardwaj：The error appeared again this morning,and I had ping localhost in the commond line,it's all right,nothing wrong with it.

Comment: Where are you seeing this message? Is mysql installed on your own machine? What do you mean by "usually turned down"?

Comment: @cogsmos:Yes,I have mysql installed on my own machine.I use navicat as a client to manager the database,and the message came from that.For "usually turn down",I mean the mysql database sometimes going well,and sometimes suddenly going down.And thanks for your help.

Comment: I think mysql is just restarting as a side effect of the network being restarted. It probably has a network dependency so when the network goes up it turns on. 
The error itself just means that it cannot connect to mysql. I'm not familiar with navicat myself, but maybe someone is. Could be a bug in that application that causes it to crash the service.
There should be a log file file for mysql that may tell you why it is crashing. Try to keep track of the last thing you were doing too before the crash.

Comment: @cogsmos:Today I found a propbably reason to the case,when the mysql cannot be connect,another application dependency on the network was turned down too,and then I use 127.0.0.1 to connect to the mysql database,it's worked.So I think it's kind looks like a problem with the dns,but I'm not familiar with it,do you?By the way,thanks for you help.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

ERROR 2005 (HY000): Unknown MySQL server host 'localhost' (0)

modify list of host names for your system:

**C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts**

Make sure that you have the following entry:

**127.0.0.1 localhost** 
In my case that entry was 0.0.0.0 localhost which caussed all problem

(you may need to change modify permission to modify this file)

This performs DNS resolution of host “localhost” to the IP address 127.0.0.1.

Comment: This problem was generated in SQL Server Migration Assistant for MySQL. Your help solved it! Thanks.

Comment: One other possibility: if you have more than one MySQL instance and the second one is on a different port, mysql isn't smart enough to parse -h 127.0.0.1:3307, so you need to use --port=3307

Comment: @Brain2000 thank you for providing an answer that isn't just Windows specific and works!

Answer (score 2):

I have passed through that error today and did everything described above but didn't work for me. So I decided to view the core problem and logged onto the MySQL root folder in Windows 7 and did this solution:

1. Go to folder:

   ```
   C:\AppServ\MySQL
   ```
2. Right click and Run as Administrator these files:

   ```
   mysql_servicefix.bat

   mysql_serviceinstall.bat

   mysql_servicestart.bat
   ```

Then close the entire explorer window and reopen it or clear cache then login to phpMyAdmin again.

Answer (score 0):

The case is like :

```
 mysql connects will localhost when network is not up.
 mysql cannot connect when network is up.
```

You can try the following steps to diagnose and resolve the issue (my guess is that some other service is blocking port on which mysql is hosted):

1. Disconnect the network.
2. Stop mysql service (if windows, try from services.msc window)
3. Connect to network.
4. Try to start the mysql and see if it starts correctly.
5. Check for system logs anyways to be sure that there is no error in starting mysql service.
6. If all goes well try connecting.
7. If fails, try to do a **telnet localhost 3306** and see what output it shows.
8. Try changing the port on which mysql is hosted, default 3306, you can change to some other port which is ununsed.

This should ideally resolve the issue you are facing.

Comment: :I'll follow your step,really hope it can solve my problem,thanks for your time!

Comment: :I had follow you advice,and I do have some problem found(via step 5),but it's didn't work at last,I hope you read my post above with is my reply to cogsmos,thanks.

Comment: Instead of using some third party client at first, I would recommend you to use mysql client that is shipped with mysql itself, to verify the above tests. Maybe its just client causing you trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps to fix this error
Use \connect root@127.0.0.1 instead of \connect root@localhost

if it doesn't work then go to C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts and check the IP address attached to host name.
use that IP, so it will be.
\connect root@the_ip_address_you_found

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error below:

> ERROR 2005 (HY000): Unknown MySQL server host '%' (11001)

Because for `'john'@'%'`, I used `-h '%'` to log in to MySQL as shown below:

```
mysql -u john -h '%' -p
```

So instead, I used `-h ''` as shown below, then I could log in to MySQL:

```
mysql -u john -h '' -p
```

Answer (score 0):

I did several tests, but when I went to check it was just the service that hadn't started.
just go to Win+R, put services.msc and start the service

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).