# sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (MySQLdb.OperationalError) (2005, "Unknown MySQL server host '@localhost' (-2)")

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, mysql-python

I'm getting the following error while trying to create a State table with sqlalchemy.

```
$ ./6-model_state.py root Passwd123@ db1_0e_6_usa
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/home/vagrant/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3292, in raw_connection

  ...

sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (MySQLdb.OperationalError) (2005, "Unknown MySQL server host '@localhost' (-2)")
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/e3q8)
```

I am using MySQLdb to connect to MySQL.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base


Base = declarative_base()


class State(Base):
   
    __tablename__ = "states"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(128), nullable=False)
```

sql code:

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS db1_0e_6_usa;
USE db1_0e_6_usa;
SHOW CREATE TABLE states;
```

The testing script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import sys
from model_state import Base, State

from sqlalchemy import (create_engine)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    engine = create_engine('mysql+mysqldb://{}:{}@localhost/{}'.format(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2], sys.argv[3]), pool_pre_ping=True)
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

I've installed sqlalchemy==2.0.23 amd mysqlclient==2.0.3 using pip, MySQL server configurations are working correct. I would like to know where the issue is and how I can solve it.

- The port being used is 3306 for mysql.
- "ufw" is deactivated so there is no port blocking.
- Root user has all the privileges
- MySQL service is running
- `sudo nano /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf`, the bind address is correct `bind-address = 127.0.0.1`

NB: The error was too long, I couldn't post all of it due to character limit on the post.

Comment: Have you seen this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16580370/mysql-error-2005-unknown-mysql-server-host-localhost11001